# A good metric for measuring the "similarity" between a number and a series of numbers of unknown distribution

Tags: similarities

I'm very new to stats so please excuse me if some of my terminologies are wrong.

I have a series of N numbers, and I don't know the distribution of these numbers.  Now, I have another number K, and I want to compute how "similar" K is to the N numbers in the original series.

My question is what's the best metric to use for computing the similarity, assuming I know nothing about the distribution of the N original numbers.  For instance, one way to do it would be to compute the mean and the standard deviation of the original series, and see how many standard deviations K is from the mean.  But I don't know whether that's the best way to do it.

Comment: You state "assuming I know nothing about the distribution of the N original numbers", but the concepts of mean and standard deviation make sense when you are dealing with (approximately) Normal distributions.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking this question... if I knew it was a normal distribution, then I would just go with mean and standard deviation.  But the thing is I don't know.

Comment: If you want to avoid any assumption about distribution and try to fit your data, you can use the median and the interquartile range --- e.g. you can see if K lies in the interquartile range (25-75 percentile)